# Aligning contents in HStack

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to setup alignments in a list

I have the below code, which works fine if all 3 items are showing, but if only two are showing the the second item is out of alignment.

I have the below code

```swift
List {
    ForEach(adventureMode) { adMode in
        HStack {
            Text("Image")
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Stage: \(adMode.stage)")
                Text("Steps: \(adMode.steps)")
            }
            if adMode.unlock {
                Spacer()
                Text("Route Unlock")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which positions it as

[image]

What I want is for the positioning of the stage and steps to always be the middle, even if there's only 2 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the effect you want is to play around with the opacity of the Route Unlock Text. Here is the updated code.

```
List {
    ForEach(adventureMode) { adMode in
        HStack {
            Text("Image")
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Stage: \(adMode.stage)")
                Text("Steps: \(adMode.steps)")
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Route Unlock")
                .opacity(adMode.isUnlock ? 1 : 0) // <-- Add this
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it after changing it to .opacity(adMode.unlock ? 1 : 0